# Getting device location as empty in dialogflow webhook request

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi i'm trying to get device location of the user by asking permission.It works fine for simulator but when i tested with google mini device getting undefined  for device location in webhook request.Below is the code

```
const {Permission} = require('actions-on-google');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
conv.ask(new Permission({context:'To Locate You',permissions:'DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION'}));
function userinfo(agent){
        var conv=agent.conv();
        var resp=conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION');
    console.log(conv.device.location);
    if(resp){

                var country=conv.device.location.country;
                var speech="you are located in "+country;
                conv.ask(speech);
                agent.add(conv);
        }else{
            conv.ask('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are');
            agent.add(conv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix the `dialogflow-fulfillment` and `actions-on-google` libraries. The data types aren't necessarily going to be compatible. If you require features specific to Actions on Google, you should use `actions-on-google` completely. If you require compatibility between a variety of platforms supported by Dialogflow, use `dialogflow-fulfillment`.

Comment: i'm using dialogflow because i dont get post webhook request for heroku from actions-on-google library so.

Comment: That seems like it should be a separate question on StackOverflow. Either way, you should use one library.